# Defining subclasses with common import methods

Tags: python, file, class, import, subclass

I have been building a python image processing module for working with images related to laser beams.  The images differ in their content (laser beam image, scattered light image, etc.) and the file types differ based on the instrument used to capture the images.  But any one of the file types may contain any one of the content types.

The structure of the module currently is

- **Parent Class:** contains methods common to all types of content

  - **Child Class 1:** contains methods useful for content type 1

    - **Grandchild Class 1:** only an `__init__()` statement for importing file type a
    - **Grandchild Class 2:** only an `__init__()` statement for importing file type b
  - **Child Class 2:** contains methods useful for content type 2

    - **Grandchild Class 1:** only an `__init__()` statement for importing file type a
    - **Grandchild Class 2:** only an `__init__()` statement for importing file type b

The issue is that the grandchildren classes are essentially identical because they contain code for importing different types of files which may contain content from either child class.

**Is there a more elegant/pythonic way to do this?**

---

I should note that the different file types require different pre-processing, so the solution is not as simple as using e.g. PIL which can recognize the standard image file extensions.

Comment: Without providing code, this question is just a really *ugly and unreadable* list. Try and edit and provide something we can all work with.

Comment: I would create 2 mixins classes, 1 for importing file type a and the other one for file type b and add them to the subclasses accordingly

Comment: @Apero I wasn't familiar with mixins; that essentially answers my question.  Thanks!

Comment: @Jim For the large number of subclasses, the skeleton code I was initially writing felt much less readable than this list, but perhaps I was mistaken.  At any rate, Apero's comment essentially answers my question.

Comment: That's understandable, I guess. I hope I didn't offend you by judging yo list-creating skillz. Anyway, if you can provide a good answer to this question, do so (but *no big complex lists!*). If not, you can always delete the whole Q. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 mixin classes:

```
class FileTypeAMixin:
    <logic>

class FileTypeBMixin:
    <logic>

class Parent:
    <logic>

class Child1(Parent):
    <logic>

class Child2(Parent):
    <logic>

class Child1GrandChild1(FileTypeAMixin, Child1):
    <logic>

class Child1GrandChild2(FileTypeBMixin, Child1):
    <logic>

class Child2GrandChild1(FileTypeAMixin, Child2):
    <logic>

class Child2GrandChild2(FileTypeBMixin, Child2):
    <logic>
```

**EDIT**
As pointed out by the OP, it is recommended to always put the mixins before the parent classes, in order to prevent strange `MRO` behavior when calling `super()` in case each of the parent classes/mixins have the same methods implemented.